# Why ng-repeat not displaying items in div

Tags: angularjs

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1xsZ.png) I'm trying to display some items in div During the tracing time i'm getting the values but why its not display in div

```
 app.controller('Helloctrls', ['$scope', '$http', 'Servicemsgs', function ($scope, $http, Servicemsgs) {
     $scope.localSearch = function (str) {                      
                 var ser = Servicemsgs.GetFun(str.description.CourseId);
                    ser.then(function (d) {
                        $scope.SerchDetails = d.data;
                    })
                }
    }])
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="Helloctrls">
    <div postit"" ng-cloak="" angucomplete-alt id="ex1_dropdown" placeholder="Search countries" pause="100" selected-object="localSearch"
         local-data="Countries" search-fields="CourseName" title-field="CourseName" minlength="1" maximumlength="3" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight">   

        <div ng-repeat="ss in SerchDetails">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {{ss.Action}}
                </li>
                <li>
                    {{ss.Countrolle}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is not an array, it has only 1 object, change like this,

```
 <div ng-repeat="ss in SerchDetails[0]">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {{ss.Action}}
                </li>
                <li>
                    {{ss.Countrolle}}
                </li>
            </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: try  $scope.SerchDetails = d;